# Having trouble reading Movielens 1M data set ratings.dat file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hobbyist - New to python

Hi There, I'm work through Wes McKinney's Python for Data Analysis book. I just started working on the MovieLens 1M Data Set and for the life of me I can't get my code to work for the ratings.dat file. It works fine for movies.dat and users.dat file but I keep getting an error with the ratings.dat file. I have downloaded copies of ratings.dat from github and movielens.org but I get the same error. I have renamed the file but I still get the same error. I moved to a different dir but I still get the same error. I'm guessing I have some config issue?

---

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.

Welcome to pylab, a matplotlib-based Python environment [backend: TkAgg].
For more information, type 'help(pylab)'.

import pandas as pd

rnames = ['user_id','movie_id','rating','timestamp']

ratings = pd.read_table('e:\ratings.dat',sep='',header=None,names=rnames)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5513dd9baafa> in <module>()
      3 rnames = ['user_id','movie_id','rating','timestamp']
      4 
----> 5 ratings = pd.read_table('e:\ratings.dat',sep='',header=None,names=rnames)
      6 

E:\Python27_new\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote, escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator, header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer, na_values, true_values, false_values, delimiter, converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment, decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser, memory_map, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose, encoding, squeeze)
    397                     buffer_lines=buffer_lines)
    398 
--> 399         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    400 
    401     parser_f.__name__ = name

E:\Python27_new\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    206 
    207     # Create the parser.
--> 208     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    209 
    210     if nrows is not None:

E:\Python27_new\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    505             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    506 
--> 507         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    508 
    509     def _get_options_with_defaults(self, engine):

E:\Python27_new\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _make_engine(self, engine)
    607     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    608         if engine == 'c':
--> 609             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    610         else:
    611             if engine == 'python':

E:\Python27_new\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
    888         # #2442
    889         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
--> 890         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
    891 
    892         # XXX

E:\Python27_new\lib\site-packages\pandas\_parser.pyd in pandas._parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\src\parser.c:2771)()

E:\Python27_new\lib\site-packages\pandas\_parser.pyd in pandas._parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\src\parser.c:4810)()

atings.dat does not exist
```

---

The last line of the error always has the first part of the file name truncated. As noted before, the same code works fine for movies.dat and users.dat.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding escape to your source path `e:\ratings.dat` to `e:\\ratings.dat`

Answer (score 1):

You should write the pathstring as a raw string (notice the `r` before it):

```
ratings = pd.read_table(r'e:\ratings.dat', sep='', header=None, names=rnames)
```

The reason this wasn't working is because `\r` has a special meaning (carriage return) which isn't part of the files path, meaning python can't find the file. Raw string escapes all special characters.
You can see this in the following:

```
In [1]: print ('\r')


In [2]: print (r'\r')
\r
```

*Equivalently you can "escape" every `\` character as @pravin suggests (with `\\`).*